# jdk7 RessourceBundle / logging issue

Tags: java, java-7, java.util.logging

I noticed that the localized message of a Level class from java.util.logging does not work on Java7. Looks like there is an issue with loading `RessourceBundle` for `sun.util.logging.resources.logging`

Let's consider following snippet

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMANY);
String msg = Level.SEVERE.getLocalizedName();
System.err.println(msg);
```

On java 6 it prints

```
SCHWERWIEGEND
```

On java 7 it prints

```
SEVERE
```

I read an article explaing that the Locale class was re-implemented in jdk7. Still, this seems to be werid. I also tried on Java 7 setting

```
Locale.setDefault(Category.DISPLAY, Locale.GERMANY);
then 
Locale.setDefault(Category.FORMAT, Locale.GERMANY);
finally 
System.setProperty("sun.locale.formatasdefault", "true");
```

but neither seem to work.

Is this a bug in the JVM or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to [JDK-8028233](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028233).  You can change the date format by specifying the a format string through the "[java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html).format" system property or LogManager property.